# How to purge chrome.identity cache?

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome plugin that uses `chrome.identity` API. There are two distinct flows, one for authenticated users and another for non-authenticated ones. During testing, the problem I'm facing is, if I authenticate the user calling `getAuthToken()` and then disconnect the connected app from Google account, the plugin still takes the authenticated flow, because I believe `chrome.identity` framework caches the authentication token. I need to actually wait for some time for `getAuthToken()` to "realize" that the authentication has been revoked and then the authentication dialog pops up. Is there any way to forcefully purge the `chrome.identity` cache?

Comment: Have you tried [removeCachedAuthToken](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-removeCachedAuthToken)?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken`. According to [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-removeCachedAuthToken):

> Removes an OAuth2 access token from the Identity API's token cache.

You have to pass the token you want removed in the first argument, so if you acquired a token with:

```
var myToken;
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive:true}, function(token){
    if (token) myToken = token;
});
```

You then use:

```
chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken({token:myToken},function(){
    //token was removed from cache
});
```

Comment: `getAuthToken` API works for me, but `removeCachedAuthToken` doesn't remove the authToken, because after I ran it, `getAuthToken` API  call gives me the token right away.   Wonder why.